# Why does RemoveDuplicates code leaves the top cell duplicated?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the .RemoveDuplicates code to remove duplicated values but it does not delete the top row value as a duplicate. As an example if John Smith is the top value and John Smith also appears down the list in another row the final result will have John Smith twice. The data changes daily but no matter what I try the top row value is still duplicated.

Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

```
LastRow = Sheets("Pipeline").Cells(Sheets("Pipeline").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Pipeline").Range("B11:B" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CopyToRange:=Sheets(2).Range("D2"), Unique:=True
Range("A10").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("A11").Select

LastRow2 = Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets(2).Range("D2:D" & LastRow2).Copy
Sheets("Validation Data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("Validation Data").Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: `Header:=xlYes` should be `Header:=xlNo`

Comment: I tried that with the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Advanced Filter needs a column caption. Therefore, if you don't have one, Excel will presume that the first cell in your range is the caption and will not include it in its selection of unique values.

Extend the range upward to B10 but be sure not to leave B10 blank. Whatever caption you have in B10 will appear in Sheet2!D2 and you can delete it there after the process is finished if it isn't needed. Similarly, if B10 is normally blank you can fill it in with something before applying the filter and remove that text both in B10 and Sheet2!D2 before you shut down the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a known issue with advanced filter copy. You don't need to perform two different actions to remove duplicates. Just copy the range from the "Pipeline" sheet to the "Validation Data" sheet, and use `RemoveDuplicates`. Though I prefer the "equals method" to Copy/Paste. Comments are provided in the code. If you have any questions, please ask.

```
'Always define and set your variables; source worksheet, last row, copy range, copy range row count, and destination worksheet

Dim srcws As Worksheet: Set srcws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pipeline")
Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = srcws.Cells(srcws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Dim cpyRng As Range: Set cpyRng = srcws.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
Dim cnt As Long: cnt = cpyRng.Rows.Count

Dim destws As Worksheet: Set destws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation Data")

'Use "equals method" to transfer a range from one sheet to another
'destws is the sheet you will be moving the data to from the srcws
'Resize the destination range with "cnt" to ensure it is equal to the source range

    With destws
        .Range("A2").Resize(cnt).Value = cpyRng.Value
        .Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you GMalc, I will keep this piece of code for future projects.